# Python scraping data - IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, split, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am getting an error the second time it is spliting. First line works fine after i added strip(). Can anyone help me find out the issue?

```
for i in linkUG:
new = requests.get(i)
soup_new = BeautifulSoup(new.content.decode(encoding='UTF-8'), "lxml")
tb = soup_new.find("table", {"id":"course_catalog_table"})

for j in tb.findAll("td"):
     Allinfo.append(j.text)
for i in Allinfo[::5]:
    name.append(i)
for i in Allinfo[1::5]:
    title.append(i)
for i in Allinfo[2::5]:
    credits.append(i)
for i in Allinfo[3::5]:
    school.append(i)
for i in Allinfo[4::5]:
    description.append(i)
for i in description:
        i = i.strip().strip('\n')
        if i:
            coursedescription.append(i.split('\t')[6])
            **prereq_classroomhrs.append(i.split('\t')[12])**
```

I am accessing the 12th item in the list because I want I want the last element --> Classroom Hours - Laboratory and/or Studio Hours \u2013 Course Credits: 3-0-3'

Comment: Are you sure there is has a 12th element ? Try to print `i.split('\t')` to see how long it is.

Comment: That prints --> " [u'A study of accounting fundamentals. Topics include the accounting cycle, statement preparation, systems, asset valuations, accounting concepts, and principles for the sole proprietorship.  ', u'', u'                            ', u'', u'', u'', u'\nClassroom Hours - Laboratory and/or Studio Hours \u2013 Course Credits: 3-0-3']
"

Comment: You don't have 12 elements in this ? Why are you trying to call the 12th element ?

Comment: I want the last element -->  Classroom Hours - Laboratory and/or Studio Hours \u2013 Course Credits: 3-0-3'

Answer (score 0):

To get the last element in a list you access

```
i.split('\t')[-1]
```

then the only way you get list index out of range is if it's an empty list